# How can I find short-term private room accommodations in London?

Tags: accommodation, london, rental

I've lived in London in flats for 4 years - but am travelling at the moment.  When I return, I'll need some accommodation for 2-4 weeks - just short term.  Hostels are one option, but they're per night, dorms etc - if there's some cheapish short-term accommodation with a private room, that would be perfect.  Will have had enough of dorms after 3.5 months backpacking ;)

Comment: Will this be during University term time, or in the vacation? If the latter, then Uni accommodation is an option

Comment: Um....Mid August to Mid September?

Comment: @Mark Then you should look at uni accommodation, you can get private accommodation pretty cheap because many uni terms start in October.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try [couchsurfing.org](http://couchsurfing.org) or [hospitalityclub.org](http://hospitalityclub.org) ; people there often have a spare room, and if you can pay for it they might be happy to give you a place for a few weeks and not just for a few days.
Otherwise try [gumtree.co.uk](http://www.gumtree.co.uk) , or http://www.spareroom.co.uk/.

Comment: Most people (that I know) do couchsurfing for *completely* different motives than earning money, so I seriously doubt putting money on the table will make it easy to find a room through CS or similar services. Instead, something like http://www.airbnb.com/ might work better.

Answer (score 4):

[Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/s/London--United-Kingdom) worked a treat for us in London, there's plenty of choice in all price brackets.   (No affiliation, just a happy customer.)

Comment: This is what I used for my nearly 2-month stay in London, and again for a weekend.  I moved every week or every other week, as availability is not always predictable, but I met many people that way, and saved a ton of money versus hotels.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the sites already mentioned, you may have some luck with Craigslist's [London rooms](http://london.craigslist.co.uk/roo/) section also.